# How to store list of objects in Android app?

Tags: android

What is the most effective way to store constants objects list in Android app? I want to provide objects in json/database, show list of objects and put one of them to two activities - one with list of them, second with dynamic fragments. Parse at first app lunch from json to SharedPreference is good idea or better way is to every time get all objects list from local database?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with this objects and if they are static or changing.

Comment: I want only use it to display specific fragment for object. Object and list will be static.

Comment: This data would be structured the same? And tell me if this objects would be complex or simple. If the data would be complex I would suggest using database (SQLite for example), if data would have simple structure (no references) use SharedPreferences because reading is faster.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not too complicated and not too many objects, you also put them in a static class.

```
public class Data {

    public static List<Data> DATA = new ArrayList<>() {{
        add(new Data("Foo", 42, 3.1415)),
        add(new Data("Bar", 123, 2.718))
    }};

    public String string;
    public int i;
    public double d;

    public Data(String string, int i, double d) {
        this.string = string;
        this.i = i;
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
...
for(Data d : Data.DATA) {
    System.out.println(d.string);
}
```

Comment: 55 objects with six fields. I don't know if use static class for them if good consider write clean and good code.

Answer (score 0):

base on your data both solutions are good, you can use SharedPreference or SQLite DataBase in your app but if your data is not so complicated or so big i suggest to you that use SharedPreference and Google Gson library for converting ArrayList to String and save result in SharedPreference and convert saved data to ArrayLists (i am saving my data in all my projects and it works so good),working with SQLite is harder than SharedPreference but it has some benefits in working with big or complicated data.

Comment: But how provide data to app? List have to contain 55 small object with six fields.

Comment: do you want that data be in your app when user installed app?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to provide this data offline, inside .apk.

Comment: for that you can save data as string in a text file in assets folder and after opening app from user you can read that file as a string file and convert it to json with Gson library and save them in SharedPreference.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a sqlite database and use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/). It is quite neat, has good readability and does not take that long to implement in your project. Some might argue that it would be more appropiate out of a best practice standpoint to put the data you are describing in a local database instead of using sharedpreferences.